# How to get Makefile to put obj files in separate directory?

Tags: c, makefile

If my Makefile looks like this:

```
.PHONY: clean build all

# compilation settings
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -I$(INCLUDE_DIR) -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -std=gnu99 -pedantic -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -g

# directory paths
INCLUDE_DIR = ./include/
SRC_DIR = ./src/
OBJ_DIR = ./obj/

# file lists
CFILES = $(wildcard ./src/*.c)
OBJS = ./obj/hashtable.o ./obj/infoRetrieval.o ./obj/sort.o ./obj/search.o

# binary
BIN = search

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(BIN): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJS)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(BIN) *~
```

And the structure of my project directory looks like this:

```
.
|-- Makefile
|-- README.md
|-- include
|   |-- hashtable.h
|   |-- infoRetrieval.h
|   `-- sort.h
|-- obj
`-- src
    |-- hashtable.c
    |-- infoRetrieval.c
    |-- p5docs
    |   |-- D1.txt
    |   |-- D2.txt
    |   `-- D3.txt
    |-- search.c
    `-- sort.c
```

Why am I getting this error message?

```
make: *** No rule to make target `obj/hashtable.o', needed by `search'.  Stop.
```

My goal is to have my project compile such that header, source, and object files are all in their own directories for organizational purposes.

Comment: Typo? `OBJ_DIR` should be defined as: `OBJ_DIR = ./obj` (without final `/`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c` is resolved, it expand to

```
./obj//%.o: ./src//%.c
```

You have an extra `/`

Just change your `OBJ_DIR` and `SRC_DIR` definitions:

```
SRC_DIR = ./src
OBJ_DIR = ./obj
```

---

You can also simplify your `Makefile` this way:

```
CFILES = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)
OBJS   = $(CFILES:$(SRC_DIR)/%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)
```

Files are still stored in `CFILES`, but the list of `OBJS` files is now automatic.

Comment: So you can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer